# Render the component lazily, on the select of a value change - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to render the component lazily, on the select of a value change.

Here is my below snippet, i am not able to see the title, nothing is rendering

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { SectionOne, SectionTwo } from "./ChildComponents";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const sectionToBeDisplayed = {
    section_one: (title = "section one") => <SectionOne title={title} />,
    section_two: (title = "section two") => <SectionTwo title={title} />
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={handleSelectChange}>
        <option disabled selected value>
          {" "}
          -- select an option --{" "}
        </option>
        <option value="section_one">SectionOne</option>
        <option value="section_two">SectionTwo</option>
      </select>
      {sectionToBeDisplayed[state]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ChildComponents.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const SectionOne = ({ title }) => {
  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
};

export const SectionTwo = ({ title }) => {
  return <h2>{title}</h2>;
};
```

So based on the selection only i need to load this component, I am newbie to react, read that we can use React.lazy but i don't see any use case like this. Also whenever i change it should not build the dom again. Should we use useMemo, I am not clear to use React.memo or useMemo, Which one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the function component:

```
// Component is a function component
const Component = (title = "section one") => <SectionOne title={title} />;

// Invoke it
<Component/>
```

---

```
const sectionToBeDisplayed = {
  section_one: ...
};

export default function App() {
  ...

  const SectionComponent = sectionToBeDisplayed[state];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <SectionComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-64100377-RenderFuncComp]

Comment: Getting this issue, but the import is correct , Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Also any idea of using lazy and useMemo for the above approach

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wood-2p0gl, Sample code snippet, changed as mentioned on the answer but still not working

Comment: @ Dennish, where you able to find the codesandbox, any idea on this

Comment: You have many mistakes in your sandbox, I fixed them, still its not related to what you asked if you have more problems just ask a new question: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-leaf-dcqi4?file=/src/App.js:297-319 and tag me

Comment: But the same code only i was having the codesandbox, confused